# Anyone use the International Domain Name (IDN) security mitigation API's? Is there a wrapper for .NET?

Tags: appsec, dns, source-code, .net

[The International Domain Name mitigation API's are available here for download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=ad6158d7-ddba-416a-9109-07607425a815&displaylang=en).

Has anyone used them since they were first published in 2006?  Are there any pending updates to them (I can't find a MSFT connect site for these)?

Lastly, is anyone aware of a .NET wrapper, or any .NET samples for this library?

Comment: Definitely on topic: This library has "several API functions specifically intended to allow applications to mitigate some of the security risks presented by this technology"

Comment: agreed, this question seems on topic to me.

Answer (score 3):

1) Microsoft's API's are limited in scope of protection.  And no a .NET wrapper does not exist.  The IDN mitigation API's are limited to conversions between IDN and ASCII (punycode) and providing some rudimentary checking of mixed script as a security precaution.

2) Something like http://www.casaba.com/products/UCAPI/ will provide more significant detection of string confusability including the presence of confusable characters in IDN. This API also allows for comparison of two strings such as:

```
IsStringConfusable(source, DetectionMethods)
AreStringsConfusable(source, target, DetectionMethods)
```

UCAPI does have a .NET API but it's neither public nor open source.

3) An open source alternative would be ICU at http://www.icu-project.org/ which includes an API also for detecting confusables similar to UCAPI above.  However ICU is C, C++, and Java only.